# Getting unknown error when connecting to Twilio in angular run function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twilio, twilio-api

I cannot connect to twilio device and i cant figure out why. I am getting the token correctly which i verifyied by console loging it. This is the code in angular where i am trying to setup the Twilio Device:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, $mdToast, PhoneFactory) {

        PhoneFactory.get_token().success(function (data) {
            Twilio.Device.setup(data.token, { debug: true, region: "ie1" });
        });
        Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
         //do stuff
        });
})
```

When i log into my app, or reload the page i get the following console, which is due to setting the debug to true in Twilio.Device setup. (see image)
[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an unknown error; it very clearly says "Auth failure".

Comment: Yes but the provided error code is not in the list of error codes found on the twilio page. Thats what i meant with unknown :-)

Comment: ok I stand corrected, the error according to Twilio is definitely "Generic unknown error".  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/errors.  As to why you are getting that sort of error, you haven't given nearly enough information here to help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: So what else can i provide...? Thats all i have so far! As you can see i try to establish the connection with Twilio in the angular app run block. And as i say the token is defiantly not the issue!

Comment: to start with, you probably should consider switching to `.then` instead of the deprecated `.success`.  beyond that, it looks like you are calling `PhoneFactory.get_token()` async and doing the setup in the callback, but then trying to do `Twilio.Device.ready` before the callback has returned.

Comment: Well that surely sounds right! Can you provide code example?

Comment: move the `Twilo.Device.Ready` function block up a line, so it is inside your callback instead of being called right after your `get_token` call.

Comment: when changing .success to .then i get this error: message: "Capability token is not valid or missing.

Comment: the signature for `.then` is slightly different, because it returns information about the promise itself.  you probably need `function(response) {Twilio.Device.setup(response.data.token ....`

Comment: Sorry having a hard time to follow, please provide full code example in an answer so i can follow more easily?!